# Disable particular fields in JSF based on user privilege

Tags: jsf-2

I want to know the way we could disabled a some UI components like rich:select, inputText,rich calendar based on user privilages.

My aim is for normal users, hte option should be disabled and for admin, it should be enabled.

For hiding the entire component, i am able to do by rendering with a condition like #{loginBean.userType=='Admin'}

Thanks
Nagaraj

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same, but you need to set that value to the fitting attribute: `disabled`, `readonly`, and so on.